# Linq where clause 2 condition order?

Tags: c#, linq

i tried this linq code for get questions

```
return (from i in db.Question 
        where i.Id == questionId || (i.RelatedId == questionId && i.IsAccept == isAccept)
        select i)
    .ToList();
```

I got 2 question but their order was wrong. Can I say to Linq get first where clause then second condition?

Note: First get `i.Id == questionId` then get second condition rows

Note2: Id and RelatedId is Guid. I am trying to do this without order by and single query

Comment: So you want to order your results without using order by? Do you see the flaw in that logic?

Comment: Why single query? Do you expect to see a significant performance boost?  Because I don't think you will get what you are looking for, with your current desired approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For database queries you can use asynchronous queries and combine result later, which makes code little bid more comprehensible and asynchronous queries will be executed almost simultaneously.

```
var byIdTask = 
    db.Question.Where(question => question.Id == questionId).ToListAsync();
var relatedTask = 
    db.Question.Where(question => question.RelatedId = questionId)
               .Where(question => question.IsAccept == isAccept)
               .ToListAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(new[] byIdTask, relatedTask);

var allQuestions = byIdTask.Result.Concat(relatedTask.Result).ToList();
```

Comment: I think when you have two query with two ToListAsync, you send two queries to the database and I think it's costly. Am I right?

Comment: Both queries will be execute almost simultaneously without waiting for each other to be completed. Pretty sure that modern database will handle two parallel queries without noticeable cost for you or for user. Two queries will give possibility to use only O(n) concatenation instead of ordering items.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep a variable which shows the returned row, satisfies which of your conditions. Then select the row together with this variable(here named as 'order') in an anonymous type. Finally, OrderBy your results based on your variable and Select your row.

```
return (from i in db.Question
        where i.Id == questionId || (i.RelatedId == questionId && i.IsAccept == isAccept)
        let order = i.Id == questionId ? 1 : 0
        select new {i, order}).Orderby(a => a.order).Select(a => a.i)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and looking work

```
List<Question> final = new List<Question>();
var result = (from i in db.Question where i.Id == questionId || (i.RelatedId == questionId && i.IsAccept == isAccept) select i).ToList();
final.Add(result.Where(a => a.Id == questionId).SingleOrDefault());
final.Add(result.Where(a => a.Id != questionId).SingleOrDefault());
```

im getting all with single query and adding them to list with conditions